# I need to name a class object with a string value from an array

Tags: c#

im really new to C# so please excuse my sloppy code

```
public Kid(string name, int age, string location)
    {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
    }
NAL = Console.ReadLine().Split(',');
Console.WriteLine("Name-{0} Age-{1} Location-{2}", NAL);
string name = "Kid" + NAL[0];
Kid [name] = new Kid(NAL[0], Int32.Parse(NAL[1]), NAL[2]);
```

i need ^ this to work but i dont understand any of the types can some one help explain this to me

Comment: What is the current issues that you are facing, while running this code? And what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i need to up to unlimited KIds to Archive them and i want to have there object name as Kid(kids name). and i dont know how to do it

Comment: Short answer is you can't do what you want to do. Longer answer is look into using a `Dictionary`. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to change is the "Kid" collection.

```
Dictionary<string, Kid> Kids = new Dictionary<string, Kid>();
Kids[name] = new Kid(NAL[0], Int32.Parse(NAL[1]), NAL[2]);
```

Using the Dictionary you can retrieve by name, adding an entry with the same name will overwrite the previous entry.

Comment: i used this and every time i

Comment: i used this and every time i    Console.WriteLine(Kids[name]);    it gives me  my namespace.KId

Comment: That is the default behaviour when you haven't overridden the ToString method on the class. You can either override ToString or write out a particular property value.

Answer (score 1):

You can't dynamically name objects like you want to in C#. You can however implement something that meets your needs using a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var kids = new Dictionary<string, Kid>()
kids.Add(name, new Kid(NAL[0], int.Parse(NAL[1]), NAL[2]);
```

You can then access the `Kid` named Sam by doing

```
kids["KidSam"]
```

This gives you access to what are essentially named `Kid` objects without the need to name every object.